# scripting file missing in umbraco 7.4 back office

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, umbraco

i m trying to make contact us page with the help of tutorial of Casper Andersen. I am using umbraco version 7.4. But compilation error as below:

public class _Page_Views_ContactPage_cshtml : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage {

I do not know what to do?

Comment: I don't see the error message, is something missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend create a new solution and install same version on Umbraco. Then copy your files to it.